# Can I optimize a standalone battery with MIP and output the charge/discharge pattern?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, battery, mixed-integer-programming

I am a beginner in Python.  I'm using the mip package to optimize a standalone battery given hourly power price in a year.  I need the program to pick 5 lowest price hours to charge the battery and 4 highest price hours to discharge it every day for a year.  But first I'm trying out the solver for 24 hours.

**Data:**

time, month, day, hour, power price (24 entries)

**Q:**

Solve for a standalone battery's optimal charging and discharging pattern

Battery rating: 1MW with 4MWh storage capability (4-hour storage)

Output: two columns of binary variables

Battery needs 4.7 hours to fully charge, and discharges for 4 hours

Round-trip efficiency 85%, charging 1 hour enables discharging of 0.85 hour

**Constraints:**

Battery state: available power >0 (cumulative charge - cumulative discharge) > 0

0 < cumulative discharge < 4

0 < cumulative charge < 4.7

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mip
from mip import Model, xsum, maximize, BINARY, CONTINUOUS, OptimizationStatus

# Define model and var
m = mip.Model(sense=maximize)
maxdischargepower = 4
maxchargepower = 4.7
H = 24
charge = [m.add_var(var_type = BINARY) for i in range(H)]
discharge = [m.add_var(var_type = BINARY) for i in range(H)]

batterystate = np.cumsum(charge) - np.cumsum(discharge)

# Define objective function
m.objective = xsum(discharge[i]*price[i] for i in range(H)) - xsum(charge[i]*price[i] for i in range (H))

# Constraints
m += np.cumsum(discharge) <= maxdischargepower
m += np.cumsum(charge) <= maxchargepower
m += np.cumsum(discharge) >= 0
m += batterystate >= 0
```

I have several questions:

1. I get a result of -1277, which is the opposite number of the sum of power price in 24 hours.  There must be something wrong with the optimizing code but I cannot find it.
2. How do I save the charge and discharge binaries in the input data file?
3. Should I iterate the optimization model for 365 days for year-round data?

Thank you.

---------------------Edit 2/19-------------------------

Here's some sample data I've been running the code on:

Or in fact, 24 random numbers would also work but these are the actual prices I've been using.

I have an entire year of the data and once I figure out how to optimize within a day should I iterate the optimization for 366 days?

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzAHY.png)

Comment: Does it discharge at a constant rate?  Does it charge slower or faster when it is nearly full than when nearly empty?  (I suspect there is some non-linearity that defeats the goal of your Question.)  Do you know the energy cost in advance?  ("Time of use billing from the utility company.)

Comment: Thanks Rick for the comment.  This is a preliminary simple model assuming linear charging and discharging.  And yes I have hourly power price data feeding into the process - this is a front-of-meter standalone battery and I'm assuming the nodal price for both charging and discharging for simplicity.

Comment: Where is `price` defined in your code? Can you make a minimum working example? The question would be easier to answer if it were possible for me to run the code and see the result you're getting.

Comment: Hi Richard.  I added some sample data to the question.  Or if you don't feel like typing in you can generate 24 random numbers for the prices.  Right now the code is discharging the battery for 24 hours.  It seems my constraint of 'cumulative charge > cumulative discharge' doesn't work and I can't figure out why.  Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the main part of the algorithm is to ask these questions at the top of each hour:

- At what time will the battery be discharged?
- Which hour between now and then will be the cheapest for recharging?
- IF that is the current hour, then turn on recharging.

It seems like that would be optimal if you can recharge in less than an hour.  I don't understand the numbers you have -- 4 and 4.7 -- sounds like you need to be recharging almost all the time.

If that is the case, the algorithm can be turned around to "avoid recharging during costly hours".

You can't wait too long to decide whether to charge or not.  I assume the cost of making the decision is essentially zero.  So, recompute every hour (at least) and don't reach forward too far.  It sounds like you have less than 5 hours before the battery will die; trying to optimize further into the future will be useless if it is dead.

Comment: Yes you are right.  The idea is to have the battery operate a full cycle a day.  It doesn't have to charge fully before discharge.  I didn't realize I'm forcing it to charge all the time.  Can you show me how to allow the battery to recharge in less than an hour?

Comment: @FoxtailFern - That sounds like a hardware question; I'm a software guy.  Are you controlling some kind of on-off switch based on sensing the battery level, time-of-day, and projected cost for future hours?  Sounds like a subroutine with 3 inputs and one boolean output.

Comment: @FoxtailFern - And I added some more to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad wording of my question.  I meant allowing the model to charge and discharge the battery.  Assuming perfect foresight for 24 hours power price and pick 4 hours to discharge and 5 hours to charge is the goal here. Thank you.